# Adding 'Add Clause' in ArcPy like with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters

I am trying to set up an input parameter that is a drop down menu which is an input layer field. I can easily do that with ModelBuilder (Add Clause).

Comment: Can you add some more information? Are you making a script tool? Or is this a script and you've having problems? Can you post the code you have and identify where the issue is?

Comment: This is a script tool. I don't have any code because I don't even know how to start. I have tried with "Right click on the script tool -> Properties -> Parameters", but couldn't find the way.

Comment: If I have understood your question you want to make a drop down parameter for a script tool that is listing fields from a layer? Parameter 1 would be your FeatureLayer and parameter 2 would be the fields. There is a property setting for parameter 2 and that would be _[obtained from](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-E4CF478D-D449-4A65-A77C-74A424FD0AF6)_  parameter 1.

Comment: I don't want to list the fields of a layer, but all the values of one specific field, so that I can select one of them as the input to my script.